# How I fix the legend in a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, legend-properties

I run the following code:

```
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, type = "o", ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 2, lty = 2, type="o")
legend(1,-1,c("group A", "group B"), pch = c(1,2), lty = c(1,2))
```

But the result I get is the following:

[wrong legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEZlP.png)

How can I fix the legend?

Answer (score 0):

You need a legend out of the plot because your generating new plot after each run, use this

```
 plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, type = "o", ylim=c(-2,2))
 lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 2, lty = 2, type="o")
 legend("bottomright",c("group A", "group B"), pch = c(1,2), lty = c(1,2), inset=c(0,1), xpd=TRUE, horiz=TRUE, bty="n")
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Looks like you actually used `"topright"`, not `"bottomright"`, though your code works as advertised.  Can you explain what is going on?

Comment: This is because of the inset(0,1) used to specify the position of the legend out side the plot. So legend "bottomright" position is the start point for the legend and then we move it to position (0,1) outside the plot. Hope this is clear